# URL patterns in Django 3

Tags: python, django, url

I am really new to Django and stuck at level 1. My problem is URL mapping.

I have the below file tree:

[image: file tree]

My `myproj2 > urls.py` has the following code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from myproj2_app import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('help/', include('myproj2_app.urls')),
]
```

And my `myproj2 > myproj2_app > urls.py` has the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.index, name='index'),
    url('help/', views.help, name='help'),
]
```

My `myproj2 > myproj2_app > views.py` has the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello This is my myproj2")

def help(request):
    print("Getting to get help at least")
    help_dict = {'help_insert' : 'HELP PAGE '}
    return render(request, 'myproj2_app/help.html', context = help_dict)
```

I have a folder `templates` in my main `myproj2` folder. In `templates` folder, I have `myproj2_app` folder and then I have two HTML files. One is `index.html` and the other is `help.html`.

I want to request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/` and see my simple help text with `{{ help_insert }}` template tag.

Could you please advise me on how I can achieve it?

Comment: To access `{{ help_insert }}` try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/help/`

Comment: Did you read documentation of including urlconfs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: I have read but I am unable to understand. I need help from someone who can make me understand why is this happening and what is o be done to make it function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a sub-path for URLs belonging to myproj2_app. Root URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myproj/', include('myproj2_app.urls')),
]
```

And also edit URLconf for myproj2_app as below:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^help/$',  views.help, name='help'),
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Now you can access help by the following link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myproj/help/
```

Comment: I tries it but it everything that i type in path returns the same index page only. I tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/myproj/help/  and also http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/help/ but both return home page

Comment: Check my answer and try again :)

Comment: Thanks it worked. It means I just needed to use re-path() instead of path!!